# Spark scala rename the map column

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to rename the `key` under map as `name`, `_1` to `rownum`, `_2` to `status`

```
  root
  |-- id: string (nullable = true)
  |-- info: map (nullable = true)
  |    |-- key: string
  |    |-- value: struct (valueContainsNull = true)
  |    |    |-- _1: long (nullable = false)
  |    |    |-- _2: string (nullable = true)
```

Please help

Answer (score 6):

The cheapest and simplest solution is to `cast` with new schema:

```
val df = Seq(("1", Map("foo" -> (1L, "bar")))).toDF("id", "info")

df.withColumn(
  "info",
  $"info".cast("map<string,struct<rownum:long,status:string>>")
).printSchema
```

```
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- info: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: struct (valueContainsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- rownum: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- status: string (nullable = true)
```

If you prefer you can use `DataType` object in place of string description, but this is much more verbose.

`key` (and `value`) cannot be renamed because there are not a part of the schema.

`udf` can offer another option, but it is subpar performance-wise, and requires a `Product` type to represent the values:

Comment: This is brilliant!